# Finding nearest city from a center place (latitude and longitude) with radius in miles

Tags: php, csv, geospatial

This is my code for finding the nearest city within a certain radius. I am not sure, is my code is OK or is it wrong? Please review and offer suggestions on my code.

```
<?
//Suppose,I have selected a city and fetch the selected city's lat and long and radius 
//in to this page.
$file_handle = fopen("Londonstations.csv", "r");
$i=0; $j=0; $k=0;
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
$locat[$i++] = $line_of_text[0];
$lat[$j++] = $line_of_text[3];
$long[$k++] = $line_of_text[4];
//print $line_of_text[0]; . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";
}
$l = $_POST['l'];//This value is received from previous page selected places latitude and longitude index from array.
$r = $_POST['r'];//This value is received from previous page selected places for //finding city that are in located in this radius
$radius = 3958.761; //earth's radius in miles
 // we'll want everything within, say, distance
$distance = $r;//This value is received from previous page, radius of selected 
 //places for finding city that are in located in this radius

// latitude boundaries 
$maxlat = $lat[$l] + rad2deg($distance / $radius);
$minlat = $lat[$l] - rad2deg($distance / $radius);

// longitude boundaries (longitude gets smaller when latitude increases)
$maxlng = $long[$l] + rad2deg($distance / $radius / cos(deg2rad($long[$l])));
$minlng = $long[$l] - rad2deg($distance / $radius / cos(deg2rad($long[$l])));
$n=1;
echo 'Nearest Stations:';
echo '<ul>';
for($ii=1;$ii<$i;$ii++){
if($lat[$ii]<=$maxlat && $lat[$ii]>=$minlat){
    if($long[$ii]<=$maxlng && $long[$ii]>=$minlng)
        echo '<li style=style:circle>'.$rs[$n++] = $locat[$ii].'</li>';
} 
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I din't check your math, because in any case the code doesn't do what it claims to do. The returned points are not within the given *distance* of the center, but belong to some square-like area.

To calculate a distance as the crow flies, notice that a cosine of the angular distance theta is

$$ \cos\theta = \cos\phi_0\cos\phi_1\cos(\psi_0 - \psi_1) + \sin\phi_0\sin\phi_1 $$

where Phi and Psi are respective latitudes and longitudes. The greater cosine, the closer points are.

Given a distance `d`, calculate `cutoff = cos(d/(2*pi*R))`. For each city in the list apply the above formula. The city is "nearby" if the result is *greater* than cutoff.